# How to obtain a list of numbers that are divided by a certain number using the filter function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function that recieves a list and a number and returns another list with all numbers that are divided by the number passed by argument. For example:

```
filter_list_by_factor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
>>> [2, 4]
```

So I thought about creating a function called is_factor:

```
def is_factor(a, b):
    return a % b == 0
```

Then, I wanted to call the function this way:

```
def filter_list_by_factor(numbers_list, number):
    return list(filter(is_factor, numbers_list))
```

But it result in this error: ***TypeError: is_factor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'***

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Is there any reason why you must do this with `filter` and not with a list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this without using filter:

```
def is_factor(a, b):
   return [i for i in a if i%b == 0]


print(is_factor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2))
```

Comment: Omg, list comprehensions are so powerful

Comment: List comprehensions are very powerful and save lots of space.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a partial function to pass the missing argument

```
from functools import partial


def is_factor(a, b):
    return a % b == 0


def filter_list_by_factor(numbers_list, number):
    return list(filter(partial(is_factor, b=number), numbers_list))
```

Or you can capture things inside a lambda

```
def filter_list_by_factor(numbers_list, number):
    return list(filter(lambda a: a % number == 0, numbers_list))
```

But as the other answers suggest, a list comprehension is probably simpler to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap it in a `lambda` or use `functools.partial`:

```
def is_factor(a, b):
    return a % b == 0

def filter_list_by_factor(numbers_list, number):
    return list(filter(lambda x: is_factor(x, number), numbers_list))

from functools import partial

def filter_list_by_factor(numbers_list, number):
    return list(filter(partial(is_factor, b=number), numbers_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter does not pass the second argument (which shouldn't be suprising - where in that line of code does it get passed the second parameter ('number' in your example)?

Try using a lambda:

```
def filter_list_by_factor(numbers_list, number):
    return list(filter(lambda x:is_factor(x,number), numbers_list))
```